# How can I flex-stretch elements to full device height on mobile Safari?

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I'm creating an accordion-like mobile webpage, trying to use the `flex` family of CSS properties.
In short, I'm getting this:
[image: Map section expanded on mobile browser]
but I want this:
[image: Map section expanded on desktop browser]

The page consists solely of a set of `<section>`s, each of them having a clickable `<header>` and an `<article>`:

```
<body>
<section id="about">
    <header><a href="#about">About</a></header>
    <article>
        This will be about.
    </article>
</section>
<section id="map">
    <header><a href="#map">Map</a></header>
    <article>
        This will be a map.
    </article>
</section>

<section id="talk">
    <header><a href="#talk">Talk</a></header>
    <article>
        This will be talk
    </article>
</section>
</body>
```

Only one `<article>` should be displayed at any given time (the rest of them hidden), so:

```
<style>
...
section:not(:target) article {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

So far, so good.
In order to use the full height of the device screen, that is, the height of the expanded section should be `deviceheight - height of all the header elements`. I've experimented with the `flex` properties, and I have no problem making it work as desired on my PC screen (using Chrome):

```
html {
    height: 100%
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background: yellow;
}

section:target {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

section:not(:target) article {
    display: none;
}

section:not(:target) {
    height: auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

section {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
}

header {
    padding: 0.2em;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, rgba(100, 100, 100, 128));
    color: white;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "American Typewriter", serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

header a {
    color: white;
}

article {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

This produces something like this, on a desktop PC with Chrome, when the *Map* section is expanded:
[image: Map section expanded on desktop browser]
The *Map* section takes all available space, just like I intended.

**Now**, with Mobile Safari, the expanded section does *not* use all available vertical space, but instead only enough to display its contents:
[image: Map section expanded on mobile browser]
As can be seen, the green *Map* section does not push the *Talk* header down to the bottom of the screen, instead the yellow `body` background color comes through.

I thought this would be rectified by specifying `height=device-height`, but that does not change anything:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=device-height"/>
```

I'd like the expanded section to use all available space, so that no yellow background color is visible. What am I missing in my CSS rules? I'd like to avoid resorting to JavaScript.

The full code can be fetched from https://gist.github.com/vramdal/4d764aef41bd39e8c96d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Safari lags a little behind Chrome in supporting `flex`.

This was simply a matter of using `-webkit` prefixes. With those in place, and removing `height=device-height`, I got exactly what I wanted.

Here's the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            height: 100%
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            align-items: stretch;
            -webkit-align-items: stretch;
            align-content: stretch;
            -webkit-align-content: stretch;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
            background: yellow;
        }

        section:target {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
        }

        section:not(:target) article {
            display: none;
        }

        section:not(:target) {
            height: auto;
            flex: 0 1 auto;
            -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
        }

        section {
            transition: flex 500ms ease-out;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: green;
            display: flex;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            align-items: stretch;
            -webkit-align-items: stretch;
            align-content: stretch;
            -webkit-align-content: stretch;
        }

        header {
            padding: 0.2em;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, rgba(100, 100, 100, 128));
            color: white;
            font-size: 12pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: "American Typewriter", serif;
            cursor: pointer;
            flex: 0 0 auto;
            -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
        }

        article {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            background-color: yellowgreen;
            flex: 1 0 auto;
            -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
        }

    </style>


</head>
<body>
<section id="About">
    <header><a href="#About">About</a></header>
    <article>
        This will be about.
    </article>
</section>
<section id="map">
    <header><a href="#map">Map</a></header>
    <article>
        This will be a map.
    </article>
</section>

<section id="talk">
    <header><a href="#talk">Talk</a></header>
    <article>
        This will be talk
    </article>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```